# Plugins and Dependencies fail to download

Tags: java, maven, struts2, dependencies

After generating a Maven Struts 2 project from the command line my next task it to test to see if it works in the browser using the command:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

It runs and looks like it's getting all the dependencies and plugin's but it fails. The error reported is the following:

```
Failed to execute goal on project myStruts: Could not resolve dependencies for project
```

On the help page it [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException) it suggests that the **POM file misses the declaration of the repository which hosts the artifact.** But I checked the POM and it seems to be good on that front:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>appfuse-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse-snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

What's going on here then?

Comment: You checked the pom--did you check the repository? It appears to have no artifacts. The default repos have all the S2 artifacts, and dependencies.

Comment: I can't post the pom.xml file because it's simply to big!

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried this at home using the same steps and it "seemed" to work - I noticed it came with a README file which states you need to download MySQL - which is what my install failed on - I downloaded it and launched it. After following the localhost:8080 it took me to a log in screen for AppFuse - not sure if Im doing the right thing here

Comment: Depends on the app. Note that appfuse is not the same as S2, so appfuse-specific questions should be tagged with appfuse.

Comment: hmm - I went with appfuse because when I was creating the project it was the closest thing to struts 2. The book im reading tells you to look for the archetype struts2-archetype-starter - which doesn't appear to be in the list